# Will a newer CPU with a few cores or an older CPU with more cores compile code faster?

Tags: memory, cpu, performance, speed, x11-forwarding

I am a university student studying computer science, and I am just starting to explore the world of servers.  I currently use a 2018 15" MacBook Pro as my main computer for writing, compiling, and running code (2.6 GHz 6 Core i7, 32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4, Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB GPU).  My MacBook Pro is great for my daily driver, as it's fairly quick at compiling code, although with the fans running at high speeds for the duration of compiling and running the code.

I have recently discovered X11 forwarding ([this article](https://fabianlee.org/2018/10/14/ubuntu-x11-forwarding-to-view-gui-applications-running-on-server-hosts/) explains it a bit), which gives me the ability to view GUIs from applications running on a server without using a VNC viewer or anything too laggy.  Given X11 forwarding, I am now wondering if running an IDE on a server and connecting to it with X11 forwarding would yield better compilation times than my laptop.  I've been looking at an HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 that has dual 8-core Sandy Bridge Xeon processors (Xeon E5-2660's), as well as 64 GB of DDR3 ECC memory.  The stock GPU in the HP (Matrox G200eH) seems abysmal compared to my Radeon Pro 560X, but I'm fairly certain that Java, Node.JS and the like tend to rely much more heavily on the CPU than they do the GPU.  I also know DDR3 memory runs significantly slower than DDR4 does, but I'm still wondering if the additional 10 cores, 20 threads with HyperThreading on the HP would yield better compilation times than my MacBook Pro would.  My house has gigabit ethernet, so networking shouldn't be a bottleneck.  Additionally, I would probably put an SSD in the HP for the operating system and apps to run on, so storage speed shouldn't be a bottleneck either.

My question is this: would running my IDEs on a dual CPU server with more CPU cores, albeit much older CPUs and hardware as a whole, be faster than running my IDEs on my MacBook Pro with fewer cores, but newer hardware?  I almost exclusively use the JetBrains suite of IDEs (based on a custom Java Runtime Environment), mainly IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm, and CLion.

Similarly, would the HP be faster for HandBrake video encoding and transcoding? I'm a teaching assistant and converting MOV files to mp4's is something I have to do regularly that runs my laptop quite hot and takes a long time.

**EDIT**: In order to be a bit less vague, the questions I am asking are the following: would Java and/or Node.JS performance be tangibly improved (benchmarks of some sort?) on the HP server due to its dual CPUs and higher core count? Would any of the other hardware factors (the CPUs being Sandy Bridge, the memory being DDR3, the significantly less-performant by benchmarks GPU, the older motherboard, etc) negatively affect Java and/or Node.JS performance, so much so that any CPU performance gains would be negligible?  Additionally, does the time it takes to transcode a video depend on the age of the CPU as well as its core count? Would the dramatic increase in cores outweigh the performance losses due to the age of the CPU? And finally, would any other hardware factors outweigh any CPU gains?

I am essentially asking if compute time for code compilation and video transcoding is more dependent upon the amount of cores a CPU has or the age of the CPU and surrounding hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DL380p will absolutely annihilate your MacBook in a brute force number crunching drag race with all of the workloads you described. Nothing you describe uses a GPU, so this won't be a factor.